# Como converter as tags de um arquivo .ris em variáveis de uma tabela?

Tags: r, microsoft-excel

Tenho um arquivo .ris com dados de pesquisadores e gostaria de converter os rótulos deste arquivos em rótulos de variáveis de colunas do excel.

Comment: Você pode exemplificar melhor o que você está tentando fazer? Você está lendo os dados em R e tentando gerar um Excel a partir disto? Quais tags exatamente você precisa converter?

Comment: Você já viu os pacotes `RefManageR`e `bibtex`? Ambos foram desenvolvidos para arquivos `.bib`, mas aparentemente não é muito difícil conveter de `.ris` para este formato.